# How can I trigger a javascript function when a Drupal ajax call is complete?

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I need to do some extra things after Drupal ajax is done inserting some stuff into the DOM. With jQuery this was brain-dead simple, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it in Drupal 7 :s

Do I add something to my ajaxified link? I read something about attaching a behavior...confusion is setting in...

Comment: 1. What is triggering the AJAX call? 2. Behaviors are the right approach. 3. They are not really hard ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up adding some additions commands to the page that is being returned by the ajax handler like this:

```
$commands = array();
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, 'grid_content_loading', array('argument1', 'argument2'));
$commands[] = ajax_command_append('#grid-content-target', $html);
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, 'grid_content_loaded', array('argument1', 'argument2'));
$page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
ajax_deliver($page);
```

And on the client side I created 2 javascript funtions through jQuery:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.grid_content_loading = function($argument1, $argument2) {
   ...
};

$.fn.grid_content_loaded = function($argument1, $argument2) {
   ...
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Have you looked at Drupal.Behaviors, like amateur barista suggested?

Comment: For example, if you want to update a hidden field with id "block", you can use: **$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#block', 'val', array($value));**

Answer (score 3):

In my project, I had already written well-defined JavaScript code that updated the page stats after an AJAX call.

Since I wanted to reuse the functions without going to the extent of "extending jQuery", I ended up with the following solution, using an existing jQuery function, instead of defining a new one.  This was inspired by what the 'flags' module does -- it simply triggers an event, and allows many Javascript event listeners to act in response, as opposed to having just a single hard-coded, custom jQuery plugin/extension as in the solution explored in the previous answers.

In a Drupal Module:

```
// in_some_ajax_function()

$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('html', 'trigger', array('MY_EVENT'));
```

In Javascript:

```
// Added an event binding to my $(document).ready();

$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).bind('MY_EVENT', function() {
    alert('MY_EVENT');
  });

});
```

I had to note that the first parameter for ajax_command_invoke is NEVER any native JavaScript objects, so the following never works, because it translates into a 'document' (element) selector:

```
// This tries to select $('document')
// ... which is nothing, since there are no 'document' elements.

$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('document', 'trigger', array('MY_EVENT'));
```

Curiously, binding on `$(document)` and triggering on `$('html')` are compatible.  I suppose you can get very creative, and bind/trigger on more specific, deeper-level elements.  If you can think of a scenario where doing so makes more sense than a top-level event trigger, please comment!

Comment: Thanks! Also you can add a second argument, next to "MY_EVENT" in this answer, to pass it to the function executed by your event in your JS code. 
For passing multiple arguments or objects you could use json_encode.
Your JS event should receive 2 arguments, your first argument is the event itself and the second argument is your JSON_ENCODED thing.

**PHP:** ajax_command_invoke('html', 'trigger',['agregar_qtip',json_encode(['#edit-linea-0-id-producto','No existe'])])

**JS:** $(document).bind('MY_EVENT', function (event, args) { });
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Code sample:

```
$commands = array();
$commands[] = array(
    'command' => 'your_js_callback', // the name of your javascript callback
    'value1'  => 'My first value',
    'value2'  => 'My second value',
);
ajax_render($commands);
```

JS Code:

```
(function($, Drupal) {
    Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.your_js_callback = function(ajax, response, status) {
        alert(response.value1);
        alert(response.value2);
    }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best option is use the jQuery `ajaxComplete` function:

```
(function($){ 
   $(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings)
   {
     alert(settings.url);
   });
}(jQuery));
```

And if you want use the function for specific ajax function you can use the identified `settings.url` for your field and change that to:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings){ 
    if (settings.url == "the path from step 1") {
        // Code to populate your fields here
    }
 });
}(jQuery));
```

This worked for me for Drupal 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack solution: Place an image inside the loaded content and give it the `onload="[javascript function]()"` attribute.
Not sure this is actually what you're looking for... Or if this is easier than the correct way... But maybe better than nothing?

Answer (score 0):

I've posted an answer to this question on so

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19404566/894487

I'm not sure of the real differences between extending `Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands` or  `$.fn`

I imagine the former would be more efficient as their is no dom traversal required to hit your function. Not sure if that is important.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on how to do this in Drupal 7: https://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/calling-function-after-ajax-event-drupal-7