# How to use ajax_command_invoke() with an argument that's a JavaScript object?

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I'd like to use `ajax_command_invoke()` to enable jQuery UI Droppable when returning from an AJAX request.

If I run the following command from the JavaScript console, jQuery UI Droppable is properly enabled:

```
jQuery('.elements-to-make-droppable').droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    jQuery( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
  }
});
```

However, when I try to return this command from my AJAX callback:

```
$commands = array();
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('.elements-to-make-droppable', 'droppable', array('{
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    jQuery( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
  }
}'));
return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
```

...it doesn't work.

How should I be doing this?

Comment: On the client side, `ajax_command_invoke()` is using `Function.prototype.apply()`, whose second argument is the third argument of `ajax_command_invoke()`.  So I guess the question becomes: is there a way to control the way the third argument is serialized, so I can pass my literal JSON object text instead of having it encoded by `ajax_command_invoke()`?

Comment: Apparently not, since [ajax_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_render/7) feeds the whole mess to `drupal_json_encode()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by creating a little jQuery Plugin that calls `droppable()`, and using `ajax_command_invoke()` to call my plugin.

In the PHP code that builds the page, I added:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/my_module.js');
```

In `my_module.js`, I added:

```
jQuery.fn.my_module_make_droppable = function() {
  jQuery(this).droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      jQuery(this).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
    }
  });
}
```

And my AJAX callback is now:

```
$commands = array();
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('.elements-to-make-droppable', 'my_module_make_droppable');
return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
```

Answer (score 1):

See also: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/73738/17676 -- instead of writing new jQuery functions, you can also use events and triggers.