# Invoke custom JS function in AJAX callback?

Tags: 7, ajax

Is it possible to invoke a custom JS function in an AJAX callback?

```
function MY_MODULE_ajax_callback() {
  // Define a new array to hold our AJAX commands.
  $ajax_commands = array();

  // Create a new AJAX command that replaces the #page text with our own text.
  $ajax_commands[] = [CUSTOM JS FUNCTION]

  // Return our commandS
  return array('#type' => 'ajax','#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is. Or at least it should be possible. Any particular problems?

Comment: this seems to be a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18867/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-function-when-a-drupal-ajax-call-is-complete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't run an arbitrary script, but if you can wrap your JS functionality in a jQuery plugin you can use [`ajax_command_invoke`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_invoke/7) to get the same effect, e.g.

```
$selector = 'body';
$method = 'myJqueryPlugin';
$args = array('arg1', 'arg2');

$ajax_commands[] = ajax_command_invoke($selector, $method, $args);
```

When that comes out in the front end it'll execute something equivalent to

```
$('body').myJqueryPlugin('arg1', 'arg2');
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is.

Code sample:

```
$commands = array();
$commands[] = array(
    'command' => 'your_js_callback', // the name of your javascript callback
    'value1'  => 'My first value',
    'value2'  => 'My second value',
);
```

JS Code:

```
(function($, Drupal) {
    Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.your_js_callback = function(ajax, response, status) {
        alert(response.value1);
        alert(response.value2);
    }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: this is a good example too