# extend $.fn or Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands for calling javascript after ajax callbacks

Tags: forms, ajax

*Use case*: You call ajax, and want to call some custom javascript (js) with some parameters as part of the response.

*Issue*: Two different solutions exist.

*Questions*:

- is there a preferred method or is this just a matter of style?
- are there differences in the benefits of each approach?

(there are a few questions eg [1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18867/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-function-when-a-drupal-ajax-call-is-complete) which supply different methods)

(Sorry these two examples may not be perfect - so feel free to edit)

**Extend JQuery: $.fn**

php:

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(
  NULL, 
  'mymodule_command', 
  array($data)
);
```

js:

```
$.fn.mymodule_command = function(data) {
  // dialog ajax id
  var dialogAjaxId = data.id;
  var blah = JSON.stringify(data.values);
```

};

**Extend Drupal: Drupal.ajax.prototype**

see [this example](http://www.jaypan.com/tutorial/calling-function-after-ajax-event-drupal-7)

php:

```
$commands[] = array(
  'command' => 'mymodule_command',
  'arguments' => array(...),
);
```

js:

```
Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.mymodule_command = function(ajax, response, status) { 
  console.log('mymodule_command', ajax, response, status);
  console.log('arguments', response.arguments);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending `Drupal.ajax.prototype` is the way Drupal and almost every contrib handles this.

> is there a preferred method or is this just a matter of style?
>
> are there differences in the benefits of each approach?

The preferred method would be the latter. However, note that both methods are not the same. Ajax commands are passed through `ajax_render()` function, which allows modules to alter the ajax commands by implementing `hook_ajax_render_alter(&$commands)`. If you use the former method, you will see the `invoke` as the command, which makes it difficult to figure out the exact `invoke` command.

For Javascript eyes, it's just a matter of `$.fn` (shorthand for `jQuery.prototype`) vs `Drupal.ajax.prototype`.