# Custom form Edit, populate form field value by ajax (NOT dependent fields)

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I created a views page show the submission rec from custom form.
The **SAME page**, I embed a form block(add rec) after the views.

What I try to do is when I click the views row/record `edit` link. 
it will populate the the field value to the form block WITHOUT
refresh the form. The "submit" value will change to update of
 course.

I find many examples on ajax just trigger event within same form. 
Not by click the link outside the form, any idea ? Some direction please ?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to trigger a javascript function, or a javascript event in your ajax callback
There are several different ways you can do that, some number of ways here: 
[How can I trigger a javascript function when a Drupal ajax call is complete?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18867/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-function-when-a-drupal-ajax-call-is-complete)